# How to open file in a specific application from the command line

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I want to open a .md file in a repo in visual studio code from my command line. Does anyone know the command for this?
I am using the bash shell.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

Comment: `code <name_of_file>` You need to be able to open vscode from terminal first of all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to have `Visual Studio Code CLI`. ( Try `code --version` in terminal to check if it's already installed or not ). You have to install it manually on mac OSX (see below). In windows and linux, the command line interface `code` should be readily available in the `PATH`.

To install it (in MAC)

- Launch VS Code.
- Open the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) and type ‘shell
  command’ to find the Shell Command: Install ‘code’ command in PATH
  command.

After that you can use:

```
code filename
```

to open the `filename` in `Visual Studio`.

For more information, [click](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)

`code --help` will give you more information.

For example, `code -r filename` will open the file in already opened `Visual Studio` window.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me a lot. I experimented a bit with your suggestions (Especially with code --help) and learned a lot.

Comment: You are welcome :) Glad it helped. You can also mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: Thank you!
`code filename` works in Win10 + MINGW64 too.